# Flight Reservation schema: No card showing in Google Now

Tags: google-schemas, google-now

Using Google Script (microdata format) and my own GMail account, I am sending a flight reservation schema, but the Flight card isn't showing in Google Now.

The corresponding Weather forecast cards (departure/arrival) are popping up on Google Now for android phone, but not the Flight card.

Here is the code I have used...

```
<div style='display:none;' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ReservationPackage'>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FlightReservation">
        <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="FF6600"/>
        <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
        <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Saravanan Padmanabhan"/>
            <meta itemprop="email" content="eva@mail.com"/>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="bookingAgent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Cheap Air Travel"/>
            <link itemprop="url" href="http://cheapair.com/"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="bookingTime" content="2013-01-14T13:05:00-05:00"/>
        <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2013-03-14T13:05:00-05:00"/>
        <div itemprop="programMembership" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProgramMembership">
            <meta itemprop="memberNumber" content="4BY123111"/>
            <meta itemprop="program" content="StarAlliance"/>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Flight">
            <meta itemprop="flightNumber" content="110"/>
            <div itemprop="airline" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airline">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="United"/>
                <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="UA"/>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="operatedBy" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airline">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Continental Airlines"/>
                <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="CO"/>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="departureAirport" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airport">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="San Francisco Airport"/>
                <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="SFO"/>
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="departureTime" content="2013-06-19T20:15:00-08:00"/>
            <meta itemprop="departureTerminal" content="B"/>
            <div itemprop="arrivalAirport" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airport">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="John F. Kennedy International Airport"/>
                <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="JFK"/>
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="arrivalTime" content="2013-06-20T06:30:00-05:00"/>
            <meta itemprop="arrivalTerminal" content="B"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="ticketNumber" content="FF6600"/>
        <meta itemprop="airplaneSeat" content="9A"/>
        <div itemprop="airplaneSeatClass" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AirplaneSeatClass">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Business"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="boardingGroup" content="B"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically it is the same as in the Google example, except I have changed the date and location, just in case Google Now would be based on those.

My Questions:

1. Should I be seeing a Flight card or any other cards in the Android phone apart from Weather forecast.
2. On the iPhone (4s and 5) and the iPad, no new cards appear, despite having the same schema embedded in the emails, and using the same GMail login.

For reference, I have enabled the flight card in these devices.

Could someone please explain where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this? you need to supply JSON.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/flight-reservation

Also Google schema validator is giving an error "Unknown type AirplaneSeatClass"

https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema#schema_validator

After removing the AirplaneSeatClass meta i was able to validate the email.